# How to show a file from binary string?

Tags: javascript, html, file, binaryfiles

How do I show a file from a binary string? to images files, it's possible to do by using `atob()` and then `<img src="data:image/png;base64,..`. But to a PDF file for example, is there an equivalent? or some way that say to web browser `ReadItAs("content-type:application/pdf", binaryPdf);` I hope this is clear. Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I have tried this:

```
    var metatag = document.getElementsByTagName("meta")[0];

    metatag.setAttribute("http-equiv", "Content-type");
    metatag.setAttribute("content", "application/pdf");
    document.body.innerHTML = binaryString;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to render it directly through JS code, after you download the file with HttpRequest...  People are making JS PDF readers for HTML5 - See here http://andreasgal.com/2011/06/15/pdf-js/

The other option is to embed it with an Iframe option

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to show a pdf file in browser, use iframe

```
<iframe id="abcdef" src="stargeturl" style="width: 100%; height: 800px;">
    Your browser does <em>not</em> support <code>iframe</code>
</iframe>
```